# Create a list of all classes in namespace using reflection and cast to their real type

Tags: c#, xamarin, reflection

I have an abstract class `Device`. A number of classes derive from it, which represent specific devices. So we have, e.g. `class RedDevice : Device`, `class BlueDevice : Device`, etc. They are all stored under the `Foo.Devices` namespace. Here's an overview of the structure:

```
- Foo
|  ↳ Devices (folder)
|  |   ↳ RedDevice
|  |   ↳ BlueDevice
|  ↳ Device
```

`Device.cs`:

```
internal abstract class Device
{
    internal string Path { get; set; }
}
```

`RedDevice.cs`:

```
class RedDevice
{
    internal RedDevice()
    {
        this.Path = "/path";
    }
}
```

I want to create a list with all devices under `Foo.Devices`, cast to their parent class `Device`. I can get a list of `Type`s using the following code:

```
List<System.Type> deviceTypes = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace == 
    typeof(RedDevice).Namespace).ToList();
```

But how can I cast them to `Device`? Direct cast isn't allowed by the compiler and everything else throws wrong type exceptions. Thanks!

Comment: A type object just holds metadata about a type (class). It is not an actual instance of a that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The issue was I had `internal` constructors and the `System.Activator` couldn't create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Your `deviceTypes` list contains Types (class definitions), not class *instances*. So before you cast them to `Device` you'll need to create instances of them.

If they have parameterless constructors, you can use:

```
List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
foreach (Type deviceType in deviceTypes)
{
    devices.Add((Device)Activator.CreateInstance(deviceType));
}
```

If one of the classes do require constructor parameters, it will probably be hard figuring out how to supply these.

Comment: I tried this already, but it throws: `An unhandled exception occured.`. No further description or stack trace. Could it be Mono in Xamarin that doesn't support this?

Comment: What is the exception message of the unhandled exception?

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger doesn't seem to give me any additional details.

Comment: Put a `try...catch` around this piece of code in order to get the exception while debugging. Also check if there is an `InnerException` which might contain additional information.

Comment: Here's what I've got: `Default constructor not found for type Foo.Devices.RedDevice`.

Comment: Then `RedDevice` has a constructor with one or more parameters. You can't create an instance of it without supplying these parameters.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis it doesn't. I just updated the main post with samples of the two classes.

Comment: Alternatively, there may be no public default constructor

Comment: @BurnsBA yes, I had them internal! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a method like this to search from all assemblies.

```
List<Device> GetDevices()
    {
        List<Device> devices = new List<Device>();
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var ti in assembly.DefinedTypes)
                {

                    if (ti.BaseType == typeof(Device))
                    {
                     devices.Add((Device)assembly.CreateInstance(ti.FullName));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        return devices;
    }
```